# Sql query to get top records with highest value of 2 columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that is returning SUM of 2 columns with customer first name and last name.

It is returning about 40000 records. My query is :-

```
SELECT  SUM(Orders.BusinessVolumeTotal) AS BV,
        SUM(Orders.CommissionableVolumeTotal) AS PV,
        ISNULL(Customers.FirstName,''), Customers.LastName
FROM    Customers INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
WHERE   Orders.OrderDate >= convert(DATETIME, '1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM')
        AND Orders.OrderDate < convert(DATETIME, '12/31/2013 12:00:00 AM')
GROUP BY Customers.FirstName, Customers.LastName
```

But I just want to return 10 rows with highest values in BV and PV coluymns.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 10 rows per group or overall?

Comment: @Tim, 10 rows overall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on group of two columns, you can get top 10 rows like below :

```
SELECT  TOP 10
        SUM(Orders.BusinessVolumeTotal) AS BV,
        SUM(Orders.CommissionableVolumeTotal) AS PV,
        ISNULL(Customers.FirstName,''), Customers.LastName
FROM    Customers INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
WHERE   Orders.OrderDate >= convert(DATETIME, '1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM')
        AND Orders.OrderDate < convert(DATETIME, '12/31/2013 12:00:00 AM')
GROUP BY Customers.FirstName, Customers.LastName
ORDER BY SUM(Orders.BusinessVolumeTotal) + SUM(Orders.CommissionableVolumeTotal) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks @Upendra, but it is showing "0.0000" in both BV and PV column.

Comment: Sorry, missed DESC order in query, check now

Answer (score 2):

If you want the 10 highest rows per group you can use `ROW_NUMBER` in a `CTE`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT SUM(Orders.BusinessVolumeTotal) OVER(PARTITION BY Customers.FirstName, Customers.LastName) AS BV, 
           SUM(Orders.CommissionableVolumeTotal) OVER(PARTITION BY Customers.FirstName, Customers.LastName) AS PV, 
           ISNULL(Customers.FirstName,'') As FirstName, 
           Customers.LastName,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() 
              OVER(PARTITION BY Customers.FirstName, Customers.LastName
                   ORDER BY (Orders.BusinessVolumeTotal + Orders.CommissionableVolumeTotal) DESC) 
    FROM Customers INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
    WHERE  Orders.OrderDate >= convert(DATETIME, '1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM')
    AND Orders.OrderDate < convert(DATETIME, '12/31/2013 12:00:00 AM')        
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN <= 10
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim, but it is returning more that 40000 rows and also same customer name more than once, but there should be only 10 rows.

Comment: @AnandMeena: That's why i've asked above if you want 10 rows per group or overall. Then i keep this answer for the case that someone else needs this.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get both the top 10 for BV and the top ten for PV is to write one query for each:

```
SELECT TOP 10
SUM(Orders.BusinessVolumeTotal) AS BV, SUM(Orders.CommissionableVolumeTotal) AS PV, ISNULL(Customers.FirstName,''), Customers.LastName
FROM         Customers INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
 WHERE  Orders.OrderDate >= convert(DATETIME, '1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM')
                    AND Orders.OrderDate < convert(DATETIME, '12/31/2013 12:00:00 AM')
                    GROUP BY Customers.FirstName, Customers.LastName
ORDER BY BV DESC

SELECT TOP 10
SUM(Orders.BusinessVolumeTotal) AS BV, SUM(Orders.CommissionableVolumeTotal) AS PV, ISNULL(Customers.FirstName,''), Customers.LastName
FROM         Customers INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
 WHERE  Orders.OrderDate >= convert(DATETIME, '1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM')
                    AND Orders.OrderDate < convert(DATETIME, '12/31/2013 12:00:00 AM')
                    GROUP BY Customers.FirstName, Customers.LastName
ORDER BY PV DESC
```

Comment: Thanks @David, But I need only 1 query for this.

Comment: Then add the expressions for BV and PV together as a column, give it a new alias SortRN for example and then sort by that. Or you can probably sort by expression for BV + expression for PV.